# Mousemove event in C# on Windows 7

Tags: c#

i have an issue with the mousemove event in Windows 7. 
I was trying to display a tooltip message on the mousemove event of my custom control 
It works fine in XP but not in Windows 7. 
In windows 7, it started firing the mousemove event continuously even though the mouse cursor stays over the control and not moving. 
I removed the code to display tooltip from the mousemove event and it starts working fine. 
Is there any problem in displaying the tooltip on mousemove event?? 
Any other solution to display the tooltip in mousemove??

Comment: Try this for a solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418738/why-is-mousemove-event-firing-when-left-mouse-is-clicked-only-for-mousedown-even

Comment: Make sure the tooltip is displayed far enough away from the mouse cursor.  If the cursor overlaps the tip then you'll get the effect you describe, including seeing the tip rapidly flickering on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you maintain the last Position and only process the MouseMove event if it's Position != the last position?