# JavaScript mousemove event inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm having some strange behaviour from this code:

```
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
    console.log( e.clientX, e.clientY );
});
```

It runs inside an iframe and only fires if I hold down the left mouse button and move the mouse. Moving the mouse without holding down the left button does nothing..

Any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: Can you try replacing your $(document) with a div id? It is just for debbuging purposes

Comment: you need code => `$(document).bind('mousemove',function(){...`

Comment: A quick search shows that this may happen because the mouse capture got released. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418738/why-is-mousemove-event-firing-when-left-mouse-is-clicked-only-for-mousedown-even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an iframe is a separate window, ie if the mouse leaves the iframe any action that void. you have to start it again

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", function (e) {
    var mouseMove = function (e) {
        console.log( e.clientX, e.clientY );
    };
    //[[First click==>*/
    mouseMove(e);
       $(document).bind("mousemove", mouseMove)
                  .bind("mouseup",function (e) {
                       $(document).unbind('mousemove mouseup');
                  });
});
```